# Bootstrap btn-group with same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap3 and I have some buttons in a `row`. For having the same width depending to the screen size I use `btn-group-justified` and it works well. But the labels of my buttons have some words and glyphicons and I set a possibility for line-breaks by `white-space:normal`.
But in this case the buttons have some times the wrong `height`. How can I force all buttons to have the same `height`?

```
<div class="btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button one</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button Two</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button Three and Breaky</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button Four</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button Five</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Style:

```
button {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

[Here is a jsfiddle-Link to show the challenge.](https://jsfiddle.net/xa9wvouc/)

**Edit**: Added evidence of responsive design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Please try this, hopefully it'll work. This will keep consistency among the button's height in any screen size**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var highestBox = 0;
        $('.btn-group-justified .btn').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.btn-group-justified .btn').height(highestBox);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove those .btn-group and use a-elements instead of button-elements. Within .btn-group-justified those elements will be table-cells and therefore have the same height.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to force a height and width for all of the buttons to be the same just do something like this:

```
button {
    white-space: normal !important;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work in my case. The buttons have to be responsive - this is why I use btn-group-justified. Like your answer-code I have always the same size, not the same size depending on the screen size.

Comment: Then I don't get your question. Are you looking for code that includes `@media` queries (eg, make the button have different width/height depending on the device)?